# How to link two dashboards in jasper reportsserver?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, dashboard-designer

I have three dashboards lets db1 , db2 and db3. Now db1 has two report components and db2 has two report components and db3 has two report components.

Now upon clicking report1 of db1 it should redirect to db2
and upon clicking report2 of db1 it should redirect to db3.

This is as simple as giving two hyperlinks such that upon clicking first one we should go to dashboard2 and upon clicking 2nd hyperlink we should go to dashboard3.

I hope i make sence.

Could anyone help me how to set this functionality.

Thanks.